# Create Object of class with default access modifier lying in another package

Tags: java

What I have is two package emp and p5. I have one file consisting two classes one of them is public and another is default.

```
package emp;

public class Employee{

 public void display(){
     System.out.println("from DebarredEmply");
 }

}

class DebarredEmployee{

   public void display(){
        System.out.println("from DebarredEmply");
    } 

}
```

what I want to is create the object of DebarredEmployee in class lying in another package.

```
package p5;
import emp.DebarredEmployee;

class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      DebarredEmployee dEmp = new DebarredEmployee();
      dEmp.display();
   }

}
```

I have tried above approach but it is giving me the error

```
error: DebarredEmployee is not public in emp; cannot be accessed from outside package
```

So how can I create the object of the class I want.
ps:
I know defaults are not accessible outside the package and it will work if I make the class public and move it another file, I want to do that without making new file and keeping the access modifier as default one. –sorry for some sloppy naming conventions.

Comment: Move it to its own file and make it public.

Comment: default member will not be accessible to different package. that's why you get this cause.

Comment: I know that, I want to do that without making new file and keeping the access modifier as default one.

Comment: The definition of default (or "package private") access is that it is not accessible outside its package. So if you need something to be accessible outside its package, don't make it package private.

Comment: Make it a static inner class of Employee? Access it like `Employee.DebarredEmployee`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `DebarredEmployee` class into `Employee` class as a static inner class. Like this:

```
public class Employee{

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("from DebarredEmply");
    }

    public static class DebarredEmployee{

        public void display(){
            System.out.println("from DebarredEmply");
        }

    }
}
```

And in your `p5` package, you can use `import static`:

```
import static emp.Employee.DebarredEmployee;

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        DebarredEmployee dEmp = new DebarredEmployee();
        dEmp.display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Move the `DebarredEmployee dEmp;` variable decoration outside the `main`. If you don't want `dEmp` to be **static** you can make a new method that uses the `dEmp` and have the `main` method call it.
Edit: This works because **public** variables can't be created inside methods